# How to write a 'root' RewriteRule redirecting to two different pages?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am struggling with .htaccess, I have this code:

```
<pre>
# PRODUCTS
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$     /newwebsite/product.php?category=$1&product=$2 [L,NC]

# SERVICES
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$     /newwebsite/service.php?category=$1&service=$2 [L,NC]

# PLAIN PAGES
RewriteRule ^/$                             /newwebsite/index.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^signup-free$                   /newwebsite/signup-free.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about$                         /newwebsite/content.php?page=1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio$                     /newwebsite/portfolio.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^our-stores$                    /newwebsite/our-stores.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^contact$                       /newwebsite/contact.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^products-list$                 /newwebsite/lists.php?action=products  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^services-list$                 /newwebsite/lists.php?action=services  [L,NC]
</pre>
```

My code is not working properly, I need to add something to Products and Services rules to make them redirect to 'product.php' and 'service.php' respectively, without adding no more 'slash' or 'subfolder', but I don't know what and how, I mean I just need that:

```
http://www.root.com/maintenance-services/weekly-pool-service  
  redirects to =>  
http://www.root.com/service.php?category=maintenance-services&service=weekly-pool-service
```

but at the same time I need that:

```
http://www.root.com/hot-tubs/jacuzzi 
  redirects to =>  
http://www.root.com/product.php?category=hot-tubs&product=jacuzzi
```

How can I make a difference between PRODUCTS and SERVICES, how can I tell apache to go to different pages with the same parameters?

I am confused. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make file `rewrite.php`, redirect everything there:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$     /newwebsite/rewrite.php?sub=$1&second=$2 [L,NC]
```

Put all logic in this file.

Pseudo code

```
if($_GET['sub'] exists in table "service") {
   $_GET['category'] = $_GET['sub'];
   $_GET['service'] = $_GET['second'];
   include 'service.php';
}else{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Just a quick one, how can I add this one in my code, and make it works:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /newwebsite/categories.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
Just with the first parameter and get into the category.

Comment: @human you should redirect everything into index.php and handle `$_GET` array (the easyiest way)